# Permissions for a MySQL user which will monitor replication status?

Tags: mysql, replication, permissions

I'd like to use a script to monitor the replication status of a MySQL database like in this bash script: https://gist.github.com/wesdeboer/1791632

I'd like to create a user which will only be used to query the status of the replication. So basically this user would just need to run the command:

```
"SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G"
```

What is the minimum set of permissions I need to grant a user to allow this?

(Is this even something which can be `GRANT`ed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [**MySQL Documentation on SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-slave-status.html)

Either [**SUPER**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) or [**REPLICATION CLIENT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-client) should do it. I would go with the minimum:

```
GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* to user@host;
```

Comment: In recent versions of MariaDB you may need to use ```SLAVE MONITOR``` or ```REPLICA MONITOR``` instead of ```REPLICATION CLIENT```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also GRANT SELECT in order to connect.

Comment: `SELECT` on what exactly?

Comment: I did Select on the table that was replicating, without the select grant it would not allow to connect to the database and raise an error. After SELECT was granted was able to connect no problem, could possibly be cuz of the version of the database, I was using Maria db 10.